# stop(); command not working?

Tags: actionscript-3

Edit: The play button is not functional, the second frame shouldn't be entered none-the-less.

I'm building a preloader in as3 (cs6 actions panel), the first thing I do is give a stop command, write my code, all is good. When I CTRL+ENTER everything works, but when I try to simulate the download to check if the preloader is working, it loads, and then just goes onto the second frame, a problem I don't have when I not simulating the download.

Here is the code:

```
stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameChecker1);
function frameChecker1(event:Event):void {
trace();
var loaded:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
var total:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
var percent:Number = loaded/total;
var percentRounded:uint = percent * 100;
loadingBar.scaleX = percent;
textLoading.text = percentRounded + "%";
if (total == loaded) {
    buttonPlay.alpha = percent
    }
    else {
        buttonPlay.alpha = percent/2
    }
    if (total == loaded) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameChecker1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the swf somewhere to test if it still happens. It could just be something with the built-in simulator. I can't recreate this when I copy/paste your code to an empty project. It stays on the first frame regardless.